# Limit of $n$-th derivative over factorial and exponential function

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

> Suppose $f(z)$ is analytic on the disk $|z|<1$. Prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!n^n}=0$.

When I see the $n$-th derivative, I think of the Cauchy's formula:

$$\dfrac{f^{n}(0)}{n!n^n}=\dfrac{1}{2\pi in^n}\int_C\dfrac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz$$ whenever the closed curve $C$ is contained in the disk $|z|<1$ and doesn't contain the origin.

As $n$ grows large, $n^n$ in the denominator certainly grows very large, but I don't know how to bound the term $\int_C\dfrac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz$.

Comment: If $C$ does not contain the origin, then $f(z)/z^{n+1}$ is bounded because $C$ is closed bounded so $C$ is compact and $f(z)/z^{n+1}$ is continuous on $C$, which implies $f$ is bounded on $C$.

Comment: Do you mean $f(z)/z^{n+1}$ is bounded on $C$? I don't see how you could make a conclusion that $f$ is bounded on $C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $C$ to be the circle with radius $\frac12$ centered at $0$.   (Your statement of Cauchy's formula isn't right for all closed curves, but it applies for this one.  $C$ should be simple, oriented positively, and wind around $0$.)  Then 
$$\left|\int_C\dfrac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz\right|\leq 2\pi\cdot \frac12\dfrac{\max\{|f(z)|:|z|=\frac12\}}{\left(\frac12\right)^{n+1}}=2^{n+1}\pi\max\limits_{|z|=1/2}|f(z)|.$$  The max exists because $C$ is compact and $f$ is continuous.  The result follows because $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{2^n}{n^n}=0.$$

---

Alternatively, $f(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ where the power series has radius of convergence $R\geq 1$.  Thus

$$1\geq\frac{1}{R}=\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}
=\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}n\cdot\sqrt[n]{\left|\dfrac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!n^n}\right|}.$$

This implies that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|\dfrac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!n^n}\right|}=0$, which in turn implies that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left|\dfrac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!n^n}\right|=0$.